# Assigning a key from hash to variable

Tags: perl

I have a subroutine that returns a reference to a hash. I want to get the first key from that hash and assign it a variable after the subroutine returns. Right now, I am doing this and this works but I think there should a smarter/easier way

```
my $hash = get_value();  # calling my subroutine here which returns a reference to a hash
foreach my $keys (keys %{$hash}) {
    my $test_variable = $keys; # Assigning the first key to variable
    # check if variable is not empty and exit the loop
    if (!$test_variable) {
        last;   
    }
}
```

Comment: **HASHES DO NOT STORE ELEMENTS IN ORDER** If you need order, you use an array. If you really need an ordered hash, take a look at the `Tie::IxHash` module.

Comment: Correct.  There is no "first key".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

all you need is:

```
my($test_variable) = keys %$hash;
```

Comment: What if I get 1 or more keys in that hash and all I care about is the first key to go into the test_variable ?

Comment: in this case `$test_variable` will _only_ take the first element, everything else is droped.

Comment: Perl is flexible and smart about assigning lists to lists. The parentheses around `$test_variable` make the left-hand side a one-element list, rather than a scalar. When there are more elements on the right side than the left for a list assignment, Perl ignores the extras. Similarly, when there are more elements on the left side than the right, Perl sets the rest to `undef`.

Comment: hi drnewman, If i do my($test_variable) = keys %$hash;
,  $test_variable is assigned 2 (the total number of keys). I am looking to get the value of that key.  example, my hash is  test1 => value1, test2 => value2,  I want $test_variable to be equal to test1

Comment: @user238021, You are mistaken. You must have done `my $test_variable = keys %$hash;` instead of `my($test_variable) = keys %$hash;`. The first evaluates `keys` in scalar context. The latter evaluates `keys` in list context.

Answer (score 3):

Note also, that although the other answers *will* give you the first key Perl doesn't guarantee the order of Hash elements. If you need a specific order keep a separate list of the keys and use this to access the "first" element.

e.g.:

```
my @fields = qw(a b c);

my $test_variable = get_value()->{$fields[0]};
```

Answer (score 2):

```
my $test_variable = (keys %{get_value()})[0];
```

Working from the inside out: get_value() returns a hash reference, so %{} around it dereferences it to a hash, keys on that returns the keys as an array, ()[0] gets the 0th item from that array.

However, since turning a hash into a list/array gives you items in key,value order, this works too:

```
my $test_variable = (%{get_value()})[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
my $hash = get_value(); 
keys %$hash;
my $test_variable = each %$hash;
keys %$hash;
```

Void context keys resets the hash's internal iterator.  each in scalar context returns the next key.